# aliases in .bashrc

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I am completely new to UNIX, so pardon me if this question is incredibly stupid.

I just started an internship, where I'm given access to a build server. I want to include certain aliases by default in my environment when I log in. From what I understand, the way to do it would be to include them in a .bashrc file in my $HOME directory. But it doesn't seem to work. I read somewhere that only interactive shells and user scripts would be able to read it, is that the reason it doesn't work? I'm running Bash. So how would I go about doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Only interactive shells read `.bashrc`, but that shouldn't be an issue because you're using an interactive shell, right? What did you try so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iman453, the files need to be named .bashrc and .bash_profile.  The period before the file means it is hidden.  Any idea what version of Unix or Linux the build server is running?

In my home directory I have

```
.
|-- .bash_history
|-- .bash_logout
|-- .bash_profile
|-- .bashrc
|-- .mozilla
|   |-- extensions
|   `-- plugins
|-- .ssh
|   |-- .config
|   |-- authorized_keys
|   |-- authorized_keys2
|   `-- known_hosts
|-- .viminfo
|-- .vimrc
```

The contents of my .bashrc file are:

```
# .bashrc

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi

# User specific aliases and functions
alias chknag='sudo /usr/local/nagios/bin/nagios -v /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg'
alias ducks='sudo du -cksh * | sort -n | head -50'
```

The contents of .bash_profile:

```
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin

export PATH
```

When I SSH into this machine after I authenticate I have access to the alias ducks.

Comment: Oh, changing my bash profile to mimic yours worked! Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

In your `${HOME}/.bash_profile`, add the following:

```
# source the users bashrc if it exists
if [ -e "${HOME}/.bashrc" ] ; then
  source "${HOME}/.bashrc"
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

From `man bash`:

> When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a  non-inter‐
>          active  shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes commands
>          from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists.   After  reading
>          that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile,
>          in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one  that
>          exists  and  is  readable.

and

> When  an  interactive  shell that is not a login shell is started, bash
>          reads and executes commands from  /etc/bash.bashrc  and  ~/.bashrc,  if
>          these  files  exist.

If, for example, you're logging in through a graphical user interface and then starting a terminal which is running Bash, then you're in an "interactive  shell that is not a login shell".

Answer (score 1):

You have to call .bashrc from your bash_profile. Refer here for [Execution sequence for interactive login shell](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/10/execution-sequence-for-bash_profile-bashrc-bash_login-profile-and-bash_logout/).